# Haskell add two list pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

So here I have the following on GHCI

```
>let addlist [] [] = []
>let addlist (a:as) (b:bs) = (a+b) : addlist as bs
>let x = [1..5]
>let y = [6..10]
>addlist x y
```

The last line gives me: 
   [7,9,11,13,15*** Exception: :1:5-49: Non-exhaustive patterns in function addlist

I am merely trying to add two list together into one list...:(

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to detract from sepp2k's answer, but in this case try also `let addlist = zipWith (+)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to define a function using pattern matching inside a `let`, you can't use one let per pattern as you did - that will simply define two independent functions (the second one shadowing the first).

You need to use a single let and separate the patterns using linebreaks or, in ghci where you can't use linebreaks, semicolons. So:

```
let addlist [] [] = []; addlist (a:as) (b:bs) = (a+b) : addlist as bs
```

Comment: EclipseFP is not bad - but I do most stuff with Notepad++ but I guess the usual answer will be Emacs or VI ;)

Comment: Please note that this will solve your problem at hand with GCHi but will fail with lists of different sizes

Answer (score 14):

Please not that you still have problems with "Non-exhaustive pattern-match" if the lists are not the same size! Here is a solution that works for all cases:

```
addList [] _ = []
addList _ [] = []
addList (a:as) (b:bs) = (a+b) : addList as bs
```

not the two patterns where either list is empty!

And one final note: it's a pain to write multi-line definitions in GHCi - write them in some editor into a .hs file and use `:load MyFile.hs` and `:reload` inside GHCi

Comment: It's less of a pain if you use the multi-line syntax (`:{ ... :}`), but it's still a better idea to use an editor.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `addList [] ys = ys` and `addlist xs [] = xs`?

Comment: depends on how you see it - if I add [1,2,3] and [4,5,6,7] - should it be [5,7,9] or [5,7,9,7]? I don't like the second answer so I stay with mine ....

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have a built-in function `zipWith` for merging two lists element-wise with a given function, so you can write

```
addList xs ys = zipWith (+) xs ys
```

or shorter

```
addList = zipWith (+)
```